# How to switch from jetty:run-war to jetty:run?

Tags: deployment, intellij-idea, jetty

I have a multimodule maven application running on jetty, I would like to use jetty:run to speed up development + make available to hot introduce hot deployment. I've used this tutorial:
https://gist.github.com/naaman/1053217 
but I had to use `<webAppSourceDirectory>` parameter to point onto the extracted war directory. Thing is that I can't compile the code, to see if the hot deployment works. Maven is saying that some resource is in use, so it can't be replaced. I'm working on IntelliJ IDE. Is there any way to have both jetty:run and hot deploment working with together? Any ideas are welcomed

Comment: Why don't you use IntelliJ IDEA Jetty run configuration instead? It can use an exploded artifact for deployment that will be built and updated by IDEA automatically.

Comment: "Maven is saying that some resource is in use, so it can't be replaced." If you are running on windows, this error means that the jetty server is using the file, so maven cannot replace it.

Comment: well I didn't know that there is another way of configurating jetty in IntelliJ but the one with maven configuration like the link I provided says. I will check it asap.